# Is there a way to know the creator of a GCP instance with gcloud SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to find a gcloud command that can provide information about the creator of an instance. Is there a way to achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be executing [`gcloud logging read`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read), in particular `gcloud logging read "resource.type=gce_instance"`.

You should be able to see a field called `authenticationInfo` which contains [the email address of who did a certain operation](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-control/reference/rest/v1/AuditLog#authenticationinfo). In this case, you have to look for the `method` field that has the value`compute.instances.insert` if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, See below and replace the [instance name] accordingly.

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=gce_instance AND jsonPayload.event_subtype=compute.instances.insert AND jsonPayload
.resource.name=[instance name]" | grep user
```